# Facebook Auth Emulator for Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase, facebook-authentication

I am trying to build a project that uses React Native but with Firebase's tools. My project is built using the Expo Bare Workflow and uses Invertase's React-Native-Firebase libraries to integrate with Firebase.

React-Native-Firebase v.10 and up now has support for useEmulator on Firebase Auth. However, the emulator has no support for Facebook social auth. Is there a workaround?

```
auth().useEmulator("http://localhost:9099");
```

Error when trying to login with Facebook:

```
[Error: [auth/unknown] An internal error has occurred. [ The Auth Emulator does not support facebook.com sign-in with credentials. ]]
```

***Note:** On my UI, I am still able to be redirected to Facebook, it's when I click continue button the error above is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facing the same error, with:
[ Flutter (2.2.3) + Firebase Auth emulator (9.16.0) ]

Unfortunately, it seems like at the time of this writing, this is expected behaviour. From Firebase online doc:

> Note that the emulator only supports signInWithCredential authentication for credentials retrieved from Google Sign-In, Apple, and other providers that use ID tokens implemented as JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). **Access tokens (e.g. those provided by Facebook or Twitter, which are not JWTs) are not supported.** The next section discusses an alternative in these cases.

(ref.: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#testing_idp_flows_with_manual_credential_retrieval)

I hope the Firebase team will eventually add support for Facebook Login into their Firebase Auth Emulator.